# Strange Curl behavior

Tags: php, curl

I'm currently working on a small curl project which involves getting http status codes from a large number of URLs. I've figured it out pretty much, but I encountered a problem that I can't solve: Some curl requests just doesn't get any response at all (connection timeout), although the URL works perfectly well in a browser.

I made some simplified tests looking at the curl_getinfo(). I tried to run them on several hosts, making request for the same URL. The exact same code works on some servers (curl v7.21.7, v7.69.1) and on other servers not (curl v7.62.0). Why can it be this way? Herse the simplified code:

```
$ch = curl_init('http://www.gitte.nu');

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOBODY, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 20);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 20);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 10; SM-A205U) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/81.0.4044.111 Mobile Safari/537.36');

curl_exec($ch);
$result = curl_getinfo($ch);
echo 'curl error = ', curl_error($ch), '<br />';
echo '<pre>'; print_r($result); echo '</pre>';
curl_close($ch);
```

Comment: And "does not work" means... what exactly?

Comment: A connection timeout. The response is this:
curl error = Connection timed out after 20001 milliseconds
Array
(
    [url] => http://www.gitte.nu
    [content_type] => 
    [http_code] => 0
    [header_size] => 0
    [request_size] => 0
    [filetime] => -1
    [ssl_verify_result] => 0
    [redirect_count] => 0
    [total_time] => 20.001194
    [namelookup_time] => 0.000384
    [connect_time] => 0
    [pretransfer_time] => 0
    [size_upload] => 0
    [size_download] => 0
    [speed_download] => 0
    [speed_upload] => 0
    [download_content_length] => -1
   ...

Comment: Changing the address in first line to 'http://www.google.com' gives a correct array as a response from curl_getinfo() and no errors. The exact same code (with address http://www.gitte.nu) works perfectly well on some servers, on others not.

Comment: Connection timeout could mean, that the server isn't allowed to make outbound-calls, for example by a firewall rule. Some server environments may have a proxy that must be used for outbound-calls (URL probably needs to be white-listed).

Comment: @Samson You should put the errors in your question.

Comment: Thanks for the tip to a newcomer. Now this question has been resolved.